# set user defined field in QuickFIXn NewOrderSingle()

Tags: quickfixn

i want to close a position and construct a New-Order-Single message. but failed to add a user-defined field (9041=_ID) to this message(other 
 predefined fields have been added successfully).anyone has idea about this?

Comment: http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/custom-fields-groups-and-messages.html

Comment: Thanks,John. it's helpful. i omitted this tutorial and costed me so quite a few time to seeking solution for this trivial issue.